# jQuery Scroll down While

Tags: jquery

Is it possible with jQuery to scroll down (with animation, not instant) as long as a certain variable is (not) met?

Example:

```
  var scroll = 100;
  while (scroll > 0) {

   //Scrolldown code here()

    scroll--;

  }
```

Comment: **Yes, it's possible**. Is that the answer you were looking for?

Comment: No its not possible..you have to use scroll functiion and scrollTop to make hings scrollable..your code wont scroll contents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll to element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Comment: The code above is not for scrolling down..

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like:

```
var i = 0;
while(i < 1000)
{
window.scrollTo(0, i);
i++;
}
```

The scrolling however will be instant since the loop loops almost instantly

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
 var a = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
 while(a > 120 ){
     //dosomething;
 } 

});
```